# error: redefinition of polymorphic class with a pointer in constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, polymorphism, header-files

i'm curretly trying to make a game of battleship in c++ and i am in the procces of coding three cpu levels with polymorphism,targetet board object is passed as a pointer into constructor and it works up until i try to make a drived class and i keep receiving this error :

```
error: redefinition of 'cpu_medium::cpu_medium(board&)'
```

sample of cpu_battleships.h:

```
#ifndef CPU_BATTLESHIPS_H
#define CPU_BATTLESHIPS_H
#include "board.h"

class cpu_easy
{
    public:
        cpu_easy(board &e);
        virtual ~cpu_easy();
    protected:
        board* enemy;

};
class cpu_medium : public cpu_easy
{
    public:
        cpu_medium(board &e):cpu_easy(e){};
};

#endif // CPU_BATTLESHIPS_H
```

sample of cpu_battleships.cpp

```
#include "cpu_battleships.h"
#include "board.h"
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

cpu_easy::cpu_easy(board &e)
{
    enemy=&e;
}
cpu_medium::cpu_medium(board &e):cpu_easy(e){}
{

}
```

Comment: `cpu_medium` already has a body in _cpu_battleships.h_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `cpu_medium::cpu_medium(board &e)` twice, exactly as the error message says.

In cpu_battleships.h change

```
cpu_medium(board &e):cpu_easy(e){};
```

to

```
cpu_medium(board &e);
```

That way the constructor is only defined in cpu_battleships.cpp